# Is it possible to check the type of a function parameter using chrome's devtools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

Let's say I have a simple function like this:

```
function alertMessage(message){
  alert(message);
}
alertMessage("Hello World");
```

And when I type this function's name inside Chrome's console, I get something like this.

[image]

Is it possible to get the variable type of the parameter `message`? In that case, I believe it should be `string`, since that's the parameter type for the function `alert` according to W3schools.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Javascript doesn't have variable type declarations. Types are only described informally in documentation, they're not anywhere in the actual code.

Comment: The `alert()` function will automatically convert its parameter to string. You can call it with any type of value.

Comment: This is a confusing question. Are you asking what type the actual variable is when you call `alertMessage`, or are you asking if you can find out what type it should be to call `alert`?

Comment: Hi @Barmar, Yes, what I actually want to know if I can find out what type   `message` has to be before I call the function. The javascript reference in W3Schools and Mozilla web API shows this for the native functions, but I want to know if there's a way to find this out for functions that aren't native.

Comment: There's nothing in the function definition that states what type the parameter is supposed to be. How is DevTools supposed to know?

Comment: If you put JavaDoc comments in your source code, your IDE should be able to provide this information.

Comment: But the browser's web console doesn't know about that.

Comment: Hi @Barmar, thanks. I was hoping the DevTools could show me this by basing itself in the native functions that build up the non native function, and I can see the data type for the native functions in the Javascript reference. But from the replies I got, I guess there really isn't a way to achieve this without doing it manually.

Comment: The answer is that the browser console can't do anything like this. Most functions aren't as simple as yours, it's not where the parameter is just used to call another function.

Comment: Suppose it were `if(typeof message == "string") alert(message); else return message + 3;` What would you expect it to tell you about the type?

Comment: Well, if the `alert()` function can accept any object and convert it into string to display, then the console could show the data type as object right?

Comment: It can convert any type. You can give it a number, object, string, function.

Comment: Many Javascript builtins are like this. Automatic type inference would be a waste of time to code, since there's very few functions that require specific types.

Comment: Yes, I've noticed that most builtin functions accept any type, but my original idea was to see the type for functions from libraries and code bases that are not native. I guess the only way to properly tell the type of a non-native function parameter is by looking at the definition and trying to figure it out manually then.

Answer (score 2):

Since JavaScript is dynamically typed - the type is determined during runtime - you are not able to see the type of that variable without executing the function and calling the unary [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator within the function body.

Comment: So it really isn't possible to know the type of the function parameter without executing it? Isn't there any workaround for it?

Comment: Nope - You didn't even specify it when you defined you function, where should the type come from? Anyway, have a look at: [flow](https://flow.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Try with `typeof()` like:

```js
function alertMessage(message){
  alert(typeof(message));
}
alertMessage("Hello World");
```

Comment: He wants to find out what type the `alert()` function requires, not the type of a value.

Comment: @Barmar, with "Is it possible to get the variable type of the parameter message?"--------OP want the type of `message`.

Comment: From "I believe it should be string, since that's the parameter type for the function alert according to W3schools." it seems like he wants to know what type it *should* be for calling alert.

Comment: But I agree it's a confusing question.

Comment: This solution would only work if I have access to the function's definition and if I execute the function. I was hoping I could see the type of a function parameter like the Javascript reference shows it for native functions.

Answer (score 1):

There is a JS function called typeof() that you can use to determine what a variable that is already initialized is

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

If you're looking for what alert() is expecting, you should look up the docs for that function

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp

Comment: He's not asking the type of an actual variable, he wants to find out what type of argument the `alert()` function expects.

Comment: I agree, since many responders have answered a different question than I thought it was. I've asked him for clarification.

Comment: @Barmar is right. What I actually want to find is what kind of data type the function `alertMessage()` requires. Since the function is just calling the native function `alert()`, it'd be the same data type the `alert()` function requires, which I can see in the Javascript reference.

Comment: @HebertAG But remember, `alert()` doesn't really *require* it to be that type. It will convert it to that type if it's not already.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is dynamically typed, as Kristianmitk mentioned. However, you can use `typeof` to show what it was interpreted as.

```
function alertMessage(message) {
    alert(message);
    console.log(typeof message);
}
alertMessage("Hello world");

// console output:
// string
```

Comment: This would work partially, but I'd have to execute the function this way. I was hoping I could the the type of the parameter without having to execute the function or having to change it's definition.

Comment: You can check it from Chrome DevTools when it runs by placing a breakpoint.